# How to eliminate loops using numpy array to vectorize a function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of a stock's price like below. My basic idea is to be able to find the first instance where the price is up by at least 10% and then down by 5% from the first instance where it was up by 10% and on, recursively until the end of array.

```
price_array=np.array([ 4261.48,  4261.48,  4280.56, ..., 45264.9 , 45240.  , 45215.06])
```

What i want to do is to create a new array(b) by reading the price_array from left to right where;

`b[0] = price_array[0]`

`b[1] = first value in price_array which is >= 1.1*b[0]`

`b[2] = first value in price_array after the value of b[1] which is <= 0.95*b[1]`

`b[3] = first value in price_array after the value of b[2] which is >= 1.1*b[2]`

`b[4] = first value in price_array after the value of b[3] which is <= 0.95*b[3]`

`.....................................`

`.....................................`

`.....................................`

`.....................................`

`.....................................`

`b[n] = first value in price_array after the value of b[n-1] which is .....`

How can we do that using numpy in order to eliminate loops, iterations?

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the array from the first element forward by the array until the last element-1 like this:

```
price_array[1:]/price_array[:-1]
```

You'll get an array as a result that represents exactly what you wanted.

```
result[0] = price_array[1]/price_array[0] 
.
.
.
result[n-2] = price_array[n-1]/price_array[n-2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't address what i am looking for because this answer gives only percent change between the adjacent elements.  Once you find the first element with 10% or more increase then you need to trim the array until this specific element and recreate the array starting from it, and repeat the process until the end of the array.